# Python conditional lookup

Tags: python, pandas, lookup

I have transactional table and a lookup table as below. I need add val field from df_lkp to df_txn by lookup.

For each record of `df_txn`, I need to loop thru `df_lkp`. If the `grp` field value is `a` then compare only field `a` in both tables and get match. If the `grp` value is `ab` then compare fields `a` and `b` in both tables. If it is `abc` then `a`, `b`, `c` fields should be compared to fetch val field, and so on. Is there a way this could done in pandas without a `for`-loop?

```
df_txn = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3', 3: '4', 4: '5', 5: '6', 6: '7'},
                      'amt': {0: 100, 1: 200, 2: 300, 3: 400, 4: 500, 5: 600, 6: 700},
                      'a': {0: '226', 1: '227', 2: '248', 3: '236', 4: '248', 5: '236', 6: '236'},
                      'b': {0: '0E31', 1: '0E32', 2: '0E40', 3: '0E35', 4: '0E40', 5: '0E40', 6: '0E33'}, 
                      'c': {0: '3014', 1: '3015', 2: '3016', 3: '3016', 4: '3016', 5: '3016', 6: '3016'}})

df_lkp = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: '226', 1: '227', 2: '236', 3: '237', 4: '248'}, 
                       'b': {0: '0E31', 1: '0E32', 2: '0E33', 3: '0E35', 4: '0E40'}, 
                       'c': {0: '3014', 1: '3015', 2: '3016', 3: '3018', 4: '3019'}, 
                       'grp': {0: 'a', 1: 'ab', 2: 'abc', 3: 'b', 4: 'bc'},
                       'val': {0: 'KE00CH0004', 1: 'KE00CH0003', 2: 'KE67593065', 3: 'KE67593262', 4: 'KE00CH0003'}})
```

the output

```
df_tx2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3', 3: '4', 4: '5', 5: '6', 6: '7'},
                      'amt': {0: 100, 1: 200, 2: 300, 3: 400, 4: 500, 5: 600, 6: 700},
                      'a': {0: '226', 1: '227', 2: '248', 3: '236', 4: '248', 5: '236', 6: '236'},
                      'b': {0: '0E31', 1: '0E32', 2: '0E40', 3: '0E35', 4: '0E40', 5: '0E40', 6: '0E33'}, 
                      'c': {0: '3014', 1: '3015', 2: '3016', 3: '3016', 4: '3016', 5: '3016', 6: '3016'},
                      'val': {0: 'KE00CH0004', 1: 'KE00CH0003', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: 'KE67593065'}
                      })
```

Comment: kindly add the expected output dataframe

Comment: hard to tell what you want to do.  if you code with a for loop, perhaps someone can figure equivalent without?

Comment: What do you mean by "compare only field `a` in both tables and get match"? How should "get match" work?

Comment: added output. the df_lkp table has 'val' field which i need to copy to df_txn table. to copy i need compare the 3 fields in both tables. it may not always be all 3 fields, it could just 1 or 2 or 3 fields, based on the condition from df_lkp table's grp column. if the column says 'a' then compare only the column 'a' in both table. if it is 'abc' then compare all 3 fields 'a', 'b', 'c'.